# Getting trip information from AVL data

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset, transportation

I got a problem which needed to solved using Machine learning. The problem title is "how to generate trip information based on AVL". The dataset generated from AVL device is collected by database and can be exported to csv file. I will explain the problem in 3 sections. First section, will be focused on describing the data. Second, describe the problem.

First: describing data
As you can see in the sample below, each day after the vehicle go back to depot, it send all travel information to a certain database and this database is collecting all vehicle data. The data has the following futures. Door no(Not important), Vehicle No, GPS date, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, SPEED, HEADING(Direction from 0 degree to 359 degree). The data id order Ascending ordered from the time of which engine start the AVL start to record.

[image]

Second: What is the problem and the goal?
To understand the problem, we shall understand the goal first. The goal is to extract the trips happened for each vehicle each day (where it starts and where it ends?) and how many trips occurred each day. Note, this data is a historical data but there is no training dataset since all trips are non-planned trips. So, the problem is how to get an occurred trips from this mass data.

Comment: Can you please explain AVL?

Comment: If you only need to know how many trips happened each day, isn't it sufficient to count AVL starts on a day?

Comment: AVL is a device collect some data as following ( Vehicle no., date & time , Longitude latitude , Speed , Heading) AVL stand for Automatic Vehicle Location. What is subjective is to get all trips happens in one day for each vehicle since these trip in unplanned. Example if we have vehicle A, once the engine starts the AVL will start to collect data so this is no a trip but when it moves to a destination the from the start point(which is unknow) to end point (unknow) this includes as a trip & the vehicle could make more than one trip in each day.